# Get rows having a datetime less than or equal to today ignoring time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime field and would like to select the records having a date less than or equal to today but ignoring the time part of it.

My datetime field is as below:

```
2019-05-17 13:31:15.900, 2019-05-16 13:32:17.277, 2019-05-24 15:20:03.823
```

I would like to fetch only the rows with datetime `2019-05-17 13:31:15.900` and `2019-05-16 13:32:17.277` ignoring the time part.

Any idea of how to do that in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, just cast both, your column and todays date to `DATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(dt AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try casting `GETDATE()` to a date type, to compare against tomorrow at midnight:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE dt < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS date);
-- earlier than tomorrow at midnight
```

The date when this answer was written was 17-June-2019, so the above query would return any record whose datetime is strictly *less* than 18-June-2019 at midnight.  The latest record would therefore be '2019-06-17 23:59:59'.

Comment: Does this consider the dates which are equal to the actual date?

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need to include those rows having the datetime field as today also. Not only those strictly before the actual date.